# How to write an element inside a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, element

How do I write a `<div>` inside another with jQuery?

I have a `<div>`that I can not modify in HTML because I am working in a CMS. So I want to write an element (`<div>`) inside this `<div>` with a click function.

I already have created the click function, but how do I write with jQuery a `<div>` INSIDE another specific `<div>`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could select the existing div, and append a new div to it:

```
$('#OuterDiv').append('<div id="innerDiv"></div>');
```

Comment: This is incorrect since [you're creating a sibling](http://api.jquery.com/append/), not a child.

Comment: @alejnavab: the documentation you link to has an example that shows the `append` method adding a child (around `$( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );`). How do you read that?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.clickaclick').click( function(){    
    $('.parent_div').html('<div />');
});
```

That should do it, assuming you don't care what's in that `.parent_div` . There are so many approaches to doing this kind of thing, it'd do you best to read up a bit on jQuery's DOM insertion methods.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$("#div1").click(function() {

    $(this).append("<div>new div</div>");

});
```

or this:

```
$("#div1").click(function() {

    var $div = $("<div/>")
                   .attr("id", "div2")
                   .html("new div");

    $(this).append($div);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

create a new element

```
$('<div>')
```

then append that to where you need to

```
$('<div>').text('im a new div').appendTo($('#divId'));
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery wrap() method, that will wrap you inner div inside another http://api.jquery.com/wrap/